# Returning HTML codes in django models for admin site

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin

I'm a beginner in Django and am trying to use the code below to show me how much time has passed since something has been submitted onto my site, but am getting a KeyError probably because not a proper HTML code fragment was returned. Any advice?

The Error:

Exception Type: KeyError

Exception Value:u'`<span>39 minutes ago.</span>`'

and my code:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    description = models.TextField() #if too many words make it collapsible? must i define a method for this or use css?
    likes = models.IntegerField()

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
    #
    #def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #    #to make pub_date editable for testing purposes?
    #    if not self.id:
    #        self.pub_date = datetime.datetime.today()
    #    self.modified = datetime.datetime.today()
    #    return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    #
    #
    def time_since_published(self):
        #return seconds only, minutes only, or days ago like reddit!
        timedelta = timezone.now() - self.pub_date
        if timedelta.seconds < 10:
            s = 'Just Now'
        else:
            mins = timedelta.seconds / 60
            secs = timedelta.seconds % 60
            hours = mins / 60
            mins = mins % 60
            days = hours / 24
            hours = hours % 24
            if not mins and not hours and secs:
                s = '%s seconds ago.' % secs
            elif mins and not hours:
                s = '%s minutes ago.' % mins
            elif mins and hours:
                s = '%s hours ago.' % hours
            elif days:
                s = '%s days ago.' % days

        return format_html(u'<span>{0}</span>',s)

    time_since_published.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    time_since_published.boolean = True #this is for some pretty icon to appear instead of true or false lol
    time_since_published.short_description = 'Time Since'
    time_since_published.allow_tags = True

    default_tags_choices = (
        ('none', ''),
        ('nsfw', '[NSFW]'),
        ('serious', '[Serious]')
    )
    default_tags = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=default_tags_choices, default='None')
```

Edit:
Added the error page

```
Error during template rendering

In template C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\change_list.html, error at line 91
1 hours ago.
81          {% endif %}
82        {% endblock %}
83  
84        <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post"{% if cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>{% csrf_token %}
85        {% if cl.formset %}
86          <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>
87        {% endif %}
88  
89        {% block result_list %}
90            {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
91            {% result_list cl %}
92            {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
93        {% endblock %}
94        {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
95        </form>
96      </div>
97    </div>
98  {% endblock %}
99
```

Comment: How about ``time_since_published.allow_tags = True``?

Comment: By the way, I don't think you need ``mark_safe()`` here. See [the example for ``format_html()``](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) in the docs. Try this: ``return format_html(u'<span>{0}</span>', s)``.

Comment: I added my thoughts to an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

The [Django docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> If the string given is a method of the model, `ModelAdmin` or a callable, Django will HTML-escape the output by default. If you’d rather not escape the output of the method, give the method an `allow_tags` attribute whose value is `True`.

So, add this to your code:

```
time_since_published.allow_tags = True
```

Also, since you aren't building up HTML fragments, but have a set HMTL string, you don't need to use `mark_safe()`. Try this:

```
return format_html(u'<span>{0}</span>', s)
```

See the 2nd example in [Django's docs on `format_html()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) for more information.

Lastly, you should try to clean up your coding style. It's hard to read. Lines like these:

```
mins=timedelta.seconds/60
s= '%s hours ago.'%hours
```

should instead be written like this:

```
mins = timedelta.seconds / 60
s = '%s hours ago.' % hours
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply and sorry for the sloppy coding. I just tried  what you suggested but the error persists, I've added the error page into my post.

Comment: i found the error, i forgot to delete out the time_since_published.boolean field which complicated things. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Great, glad you got it figured out.